# vmware ubuntu: error usb 4-1: stat urb: status -32 when connecting external drive

Tags: ubuntu, usb, vmware

I'm using vmware with ubuntu 14.04 LTS. 
When i try to connect my seagate M3, the virtual machine actually recognize it, but it doesn't get mounted nor recognized by the system. After a little bit of digging, looks like the device is indeed connected as the command **lsusb** shows:

```
Bus 004 Device 004: ID 0bc2:61b6 Seagate RSS LLC 
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 0e0f:0003 VMware, Inc. Virtual Mouse
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 0e0f:0002 VMware, Inc. Virtual USB Hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
```

checking the syslog showed that the system actually tries to mount it, failing:

```
Oct 16 11:42:43 ubuntu kernel: [  479.209798] usb 4-1: new SuperSpeed USB device number 4 using xhci_hcd
Oct 16 11:42:43 ubuntu kernel: [  479.228756] usb 4-1: New USB device found, idVendor=0bc2, idProduct=61b6
Oct 16 11:42:43 ubuntu kernel: [  479.228774] usb 4-1: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
Oct 16 11:42:43 ubuntu kernel: [  479.228775] usb 4-1: Product: M3
Oct 16 11:42:43 ubuntu kernel: [  479.228776] usb 4-1: Manufacturer: Seagate
Oct 16 11:42:43 ubuntu kernel: [  479.228777] usb 4-1: SerialNumber: NM124VYT
Oct 16 11:42:43 ubuntu kernel: [  479.427608] scsi host35: uas
Oct 16 11:42:43 ubuntu kernel: [  479.429253] usb 4-1: stat urb: status -32
Oct 16 11:42:43 ubuntu kernel: [  479.429273] scsi 35:0:0:0: tag#0 data cmplt err -32 uas-tag 1 inflight: CMD 
Oct 16 11:42:43 ubuntu kernel: [  479.429276] scsi 35:0:0:0: tag#0 CDB: Inquiry 12 00 00 00 24 00
Oct 16 11:42:41 ubuntu vmsvc[1298]: message repeated 10 times: [ [ warning] [guestinfo] Failed to get vmstats.]
Oct 16 11:42:43 ubuntu mtp-probe: checking bus 4, device 4: "/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:15.0/0000:03:00.0/usb4/4-1"
Oct 16 11:42:43 ubuntu mtp-probe: bus: 4, device: 4 was not an MTP device
Oct 16 11:43:04 ubuntu kernel: [  500.862644] scsi 35:0:0:0: tag#0 uas_eh_abort_handler 0 uas-tag 1 inflight: CMD 
Oct 16 11:43:04 ubuntu kernel: [  500.862650] scsi 35:0:0:0: tag#0 CDB: Inquiry 12 00 00 00 24 00
Oct 16 11:43:04 ubuntu kernel: [  500.862713] scsi host35: uas_eh_bus_reset_handler start
Oct 16 11:43:04 ubuntu kernel: [  500.977721] usb 4-1: reset SuperSpeed USB device number 4 using xhci_hcd
Oct 16 11:43:04 ubuntu kernel: [  501.014051] scsi host35: uas_eh_bus_reset_handler success
Oct 16 11:43:04 ubuntu kernel: [  501.014652] usb 4-1: stat urb: status -32
Oct 16 11:43:04 ubuntu kernel: [  501.017564] scsi 35:0:0:0: tag#0 uas_eh_abort_handler 0 uas-tag 1 inflight: CMD 
Oct 16 11:43:04 ubuntu kernel: [  501.017567] scsi 35:0:0:0: tag#0 CDB: Test Unit Ready 00 00 00 00 00 00
Oct 16 11:43:04 ubuntu kernel: [  501.017570] scsi host35: uas_eh_bus_reset_handler start
Oct 16 11:43:05 ubuntu kernel: [  501.234951] usb 4-1: reset SuperSpeed USB device number 4 using xhci_hcd
Oct 16 11:43:05 ubuntu kernel: [  501.301555] scsi host35: uas_eh_bus_reset_handler success
Oct 16 11:43:05 ubuntu kernel: [  501.301561] scsi 35:0:0:0: Device offlined - not ready after error recovery
```

Apparently i get this -32 error with this usb 4-1.

Does anyone has any idea of why this might happen? Can't find anything relevant online.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a workaround, when using a virtual machine, you can share the folder on the host, by adding it in settings>option panel>shared folders. It is considerably slower when taking in account the additional layer of comunication between guest and host, but at least you will gain access to the drive.

Answer (score 3):

the `usb 4-1` is the USB port number, `stat urb : status -32` means that *urb* ( **U**SB **r**equest **b**lock ) reports *error -32* ( broken pipe ) cf. http://www.makelinux.net/ldd3/chp-13-sect-3 for the *urb* and http://www-numi.fnal.gov/offline_software/srt_public_context/WebDocs/Errors/unix_system_errors.html for the error code

very likely the problem is the *UAS module* ( https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/USB_Attached_SCSI ), see https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=183190, https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=183723

a solution for archlinux is in https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=183190 in *Da_Coynul's* answer, it 'blacklists' the `uas` module for the specific SCSI drive by configuring the `usb-storage` module :

> I was able to get my external drive working again by telling the
>   usb-storage module to ignore uas for the device.  Here is how to do
>   it:
>
> First, create a file named `ignore_uas.conf` in the `/etc/modprobe.d`
>   directory containing the following*

```
 options usb-storage quirks=Vendor_ID:Product_ID:u
```

> *(substitute your actual Vendor_ID and Product_ID obtained from the `lsusb -v` command).
>
> Next, regenerate your inital ramdisk:

```
 # mkinitcpio -p linux
```

this solution has to be adapted for a virtual machine. maybe follow this guide : https://www.vmware.com/support/ws45/doc/disks_add_ws.html because hotplugging of SCSI devices seems not to be supported :

> Hot adding and removing SCSI devices is not supported.

source: https://docs.vmware.com/en/VMware-vSphere/6.0/com.vmware.vsphere.hostclient.doc/GUID-3E6E58AA-2AD4-4370-9955-07E5FBDE800D.html

Comment: Thanks for the info. I didn't find anything useful to adapt that solution to my problem though...At least now i know what's going on.

Comment: best answer ever solved my midi-midi sevilla soft issue :DDDDDDD

Comment: ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~【ツ】